# How to store lage text content in db from html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making an html and php form to store data in mysql database.Its working fine but for small content of text like 100-200 words but i want it to store around 500 word in database,and I dont know how to do this.My html code is

```html
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td width="250">BookName</td>
<td>
<input name="bookname" type="text" id="bookname" /><br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="250">category</td>
<td>
<input name="category" type="text" id="category" /><br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="250">releases</td>
<td>
<input name="releases" type="text" id="releases" /><br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="250">Price</td>
<td>
<input name="price" type="text" id="price" /><br />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="500">discription</td>
<td>
<input name="discription" type="text" id="discription" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="250">authorName</td>
<td>
<input name="publicationName" type="text" id="publicationName" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

and my php code is

please somebody help me.

Comment: Make the `datatype` `TEXT` in mysql for which you want to store large data.

Comment: In your database dit you use varchar ot text / long text?

Comment: use datatype `LONGTEXT`

Comment: change data type to blob

Comment: nothing works give same error that file is not uploaded but again for small content it is uploading to server

Comment: You should really not use the original filename for the uploaded file. If two user upload a file with the same filename (e.g. `2.jpg`) the newer one overwrites the old file. Generate a random filename instead (or use the SHA1 checksum of the uploaded file).

Comment: srry but how does it help me..

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: but how will it help  me

Answer (score 3):

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html)

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Comment: nothing works give same error that file is not uploaded but again for small content it is uploading to server

Comment: no error is from html page because when i m editing my sql table then it save the large content so i think threre is no problem from mysql

Answer (score 0):

Just use your datatype `TEXT` in your field to store large data. Don't specify any length in that.

Comment: That limits to 64KB and often that's inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

use `textarea` instead of `input` for large input fields.

it will be better to store the values in the "TEXT" data type.
Read the following [article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blob.html) for more info

Comment: nothing works give same error that file is not uploaded but again for small content it is uploading to server

Comment: @NickyManali There is no file input in your form?

Answer (score 0):

Use data type `TEXT` in your database against the field you want to save max data, and use `<input type="textarea" name="name of your filed"` in html form.

Comment: nothing works give same error that file is not uploaded but again for small content it is uploading to server

Comment: from which field you are trying to save the large content ?
do mention the name of fields please..

Comment: discription field

Comment: replace your description field code(html) with this one

`<textarea name="discription" id="discription" /> </textarea><br />` 

and in `MySQL` change the datatype to `LONGTEXT` like below

(http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4ugwph&s=9#.V72DZvl97IU)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add text in word document and upload it on server and save file name instead of directly inserting text into the database.